# How to display a video in OpenGL ES for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, opengl-es, avfoundation

I have been searching for resources to display a video in OpenGL ES for iPhone. Can't seem to find any sample code for doing so. The only link i found was a blog which speaks of it but does not have a guide on implementing it.

Would appreciate if anyone could point out any resources they know of or guide me of what are the steps to doing it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a sample project for this called GLVideoFrame from WWDC 2010 sample code collection